# Unity Template Yellow lines

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is an unimportant question but its been bugging me... WHAT THE HECK ARE THE YELLOW LINES AND POINTS?!?!

I have a few theories, something to do with lighting and light probes maybe? Or the UMP thing??

Like I said in my previous question, coming back to unity from some time away so it may just be a new thing I missed.

Anyone able to help me not drive myself mad?

[image: Picture of yellow bits]

Comment: A lot of components have their own Gizmo drawers so it should be quite difficult to answer if we don't know what stuff you are using in your project. Try go through the Gizmos and hide them one by one the you will see what they belong to ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I finally found out where it came from and how to remove those yellow lines. You have to go in window > rendering > Lighting, and there, you scroll down and set "Light Probe Visualisation" to None. Hoping this helps you !